# Migrating WordPress from Local to Live Error

Tags: wordpress, local

So I've migrated my wordpress from local to live and I've had a few issues with internal service error - which I mostly was able to solve. However, for some reason all my content is fully visible on the live site but when I go to the backend to edit - all of my pages are completely empty! Also, all of my images won't come up and strange black diamonds with question marks are popping up all over my site. Please let me know how I can fix this!!!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So This sounds like a problem I had before.. To solve this I done the following:

1 Re upload your uploads folder located in: `wp-content/uploads`

2 got to your admin panel and go `Settings > Permalinks` and click `save` this will re-fresh your permalinks

3 where you have images uploaded, click on them and re-select them.

This should solve your issue, Let me know if it doesnt